# QuesrySet eror in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have some models:

```
class OrdersTrigger(models.Model):
    order           = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_trigger   = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='trigger', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
....
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    from_bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, related_name='to', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm getting list of orders from this model using filters :

```
orders = OrdersTrigger.objects.filter(Q(order__from_bank_=baseBank) & Q(order__to_bank=quoteBank))\
    .filter(created_at__gte=latest_time).order_by('-created_at')
```

when i try to iterates through the list:

```
for order in orders:
```

or

```
for order in orders.all():
```

I'm receiving an error:

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result
>   using slicing.

Can you help me with this? I can not understand how to fix this error.

Comment: Seems like you are passing `baseBank` or `quoteBank` as `Queryset` but not as single instance. So put there single instance or add `__in` in your lookup if you need to filter by `Queryset`. Like `order__to_bank__in`.

Comment: May be you have added and extra Undescore(-) in `r(Q(order__from_bank_=baseBank)` line. It should be order__from_bank=baseBank. May be this will fix your issue.